# Angular to C# Http passing query parameters

Tags: c#, angular, http, query-string

I think the C# HttpGet TEMPLATE is what I am missing, but here’s the details. On the Angular front end:

```
let params = new HttpParams()
  .append('GDWarn', values[0].toString())
  .append('GDLimit', values[1].toString())
  .append('NDWarn', values[2].toString())
  .append('NDLimit', values[3].toString())
let url = `${this.url}/CalibrationModelFile/UpdateLimits/${this.networkID}/${constID}/{params}`
```

Here I assume `this.http.get(url, …` will do some magic to recognize `HttpParams` is a set of QUERY parameters.
So the C# backend to receive the http request:

```
[HttpGet("CalibrationModelFile/UpdateLimits/{networkID:int}/{ConstituentID:int}/{values}")]
public async Task UpdateConstituentLimits(int networkID, int ConstituentID, [FromQuery] double[,] values)
```

I think the `[FromQuery]` may be right, but NOT enough.  The `{values]` in the template probably should have something so we know it's QUERY PARMS?

Any thoughts?

Thanks in Advance, Yogi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sending an Array as Query Parameters

If you're trying to get a set of query params and route params like this:

```
.../UpdateLimits/networkID/ConstituentID?values=array
```

you should send a request as shown in the sample:

```
.../UpdateLimits/1/2?values=3.0&values=4.0&values=5.0
```

### Query Parameters are not Part of a Route

Action's arguments in C# will be:

```
[HttpGet("CalibrationModelFile/UpdateLimits/{networkID:int}/{ConstituentID:int}")]
public async Task UpdateConstituentLimits(int networkID, int ConstituentID, [FromQuery] double[] values)
```

In the above sample `{values}` is removed from the route because `QueryParam` is not a part of a route. Also, it's better to decorate route parameters with `[FromRoute]` attribute.

### 2D Array as Query Parameters

Now, if the case is a 2D array as a query param, a simple solution is converting a 2D array into a string and parse the string in the C# action as following code:

```
.../UpdateLimits/1/2?values=GDWarn:4.1,GDLimit:3.7,NDWarn:6.3,NDLimit:4.8
```

and parsing query string in the resulted action will be like this:

```
    [HttpGet("{networkID:int}/{ConstituentID:int}")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get([FromRoute]int networkID,
        [FromRoute]int ConstituentID, [FromQuery]string values)
    {
        // received string is: "GDWarn:4.1,GDLimit:3.7,NDWarn:6.3,NDLimit:4.8"
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        foreach (var item in values.Split(','))
            dict.Add(item.Split(':')[0], Convert.ToDouble(item.Split(':')[1]));

        return (...)

    }
```